# asp.net page login slowly because of loading main page

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication

I have asp.net website. In which when I log in, after login, it will redirect to the main page. However, the login is so slow because of loading main page. It takes almost 60 sec to log in due to the loading of the main page. Is that a way I can let user login first and see something and then make progress bar indicating the main page is being loaded

Comment: After login go to a `Bob` page which displays `You are logged in` and does a client side (JS) redirect to the main page. Alternatively, change the login page so it submits the login request via AJAX (so it can show 'login successful' before redirecting to the main page).

Comment: why it is taking 60 seconds? very long time!

Comment: May I know what is Bob page?

Comment: A new page that you write.